# How to sync .Rmd file and pdf output in Rstudio?

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown, tex

I have a .rmd file that I compile into a pdf using Knitr. I want to able to click on the pdf and have rstudio show me where in the source code that text or paragraph is. I am using Sumatra as the Rstudio PDF viewer.

Comment: I think manually using the "Find" feature (Ctrl+F) is as close as you're going to get.

Comment: This is currently not possible.